# Hibernate one to many map two foreign keys to the same column?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a table user and another table that has two colums that point to the user id how can I map the one to many relation not search for foreign key only in one of those colums, but join if any of those 2 colums point to the user. I am using Spring with hibernate and JPA.

User:

```
+------------+  
|    id      | 
+------------+
|     1      |
|     2      |
+------------+
```

Games:  (Where user1 and user2 stand for player 1 and 2 with foreign key to userId)

```
+------------+---------+--------+
|    user1   |  user2  |  game  | 
+------------+---------+---------
|      1     |    4    |   1    |
|      6     |    1    |   2    |
+------------+---------+--------+
```

I am managing to get the games of user 1 only if it is in the first column, but it doesnt get the games where user 1 is in the second column of the game table. Is there a way to do it with hibernate annotation?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL , fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "games",joinColumns ={@JoinColumn(name ="first_user", referencedColumnName ="id" )},inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ="second_user", referencedColumnName ="id" ))
    private List<Game> games;


@Entity
@Table(name = "games")
public class Game {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "first_user", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User firstUser;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "second_user", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User secondUser;
```

Comment: Take a look at `@JoinTable` annotation and `joinColumns`, `inverseJoinColumns` fields.

Comment: @VladHanzha i tried this     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL , fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "games",joinColumns ={@JoinColumn(name ="first_user", referencedColumnName ="id" )},inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ="second_user", referencedColumnName ="id" ))

Comment: @VladHanzha But like this not even one of the colums are considered. Isn't inverseJoinColums for joining 3 tables?

Comment: Can you show your Game and User entitites?

Comment: @VladHanzha I updated my answer

Comment: `I am managing to get the games of user 1 only if it is in the first column, but it doesnt get the games where user 1 is in the second column of the game table. Is there a way to do it with hibernate annotation?` Can you show your request/query where you're getting games?

Comment: @VladHanzha The thing is if I use query I don't even need to anotate as one to many? I need to get a user and hibernate to automatically get the games that he has. like user.findById and in the user hibernate to map the games